# why does data stream freeze up on httpwebrequest

Tags: stream, httpwebresponse

I am reading a continuous data stream from an api and at times the program will freeze on the following line and eventually time out.

```
Private BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 8100
...
Dim bufferread(81000) As Byte
numbytesread = responseStream.Read(bufferread, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

I could reduce the buffersize I guess and also write more frequently to my files but I also want to make sure I create good files where data is not snipped off and I reach a delimitter which indicates end of a post. Any ideas on why this freezes up.

Comment: 8100 vs 81000... is that a typo

Comment: no actually I was playing around with the size hoping that would help but eventually made it both 8100

Comment: what do you mean runtime...visual studio 2010